# IBM Watson Visual Recognition : UnauthorizedException

Tags: android, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, visual-recognition

I am getting **com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.service.exception.UnauthorizedException: Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials** error while i am using the right credentials. I am doing like this..

Imports :

```
import com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.visual_recognition.v2_beta.VisualRecognition;
import com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.visual_recognition.v2_beta.model.VisualClassification;
```

Code :

```
service = new VisualRecognition(VisualRecognition.VERSION_DATE_2015_12_02);
service.setUsernameAndPassword("GXXXXxxxxxxx", "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"); 

File image = new File("src/test/resources/visual_recognition/car.png");
VisualClassification result = service.classify(image).execute();
```

Dependencies :

```
compile 'com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud:java-sdk:3.0.0-RC1'
```

Where on Bluemix the **Visual Recognition** credentials are like this

```
{
 "credentials": {
 "url": "https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/visual-recognition-beta/api",
 "password": "GXXXXxxxxxxx",
 "username": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
 }
}
```

Please help me to solve the issue. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be an error in your question, rather than an error in your code, however please double check that you pass to *setUsernameAndPassword* method the parameters in the correct order (username, password) as specified in the [API Reference](http://www.ibm.com/smarterplanet/us/en/ibmwatson/developercloud/visual-recognition/api/v2/?java#authentication). Looking at your code I see

```
service.setUsernameAndPassword("GXXXXxxxxxxx", "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx");
```

that is *(password, username)*. I've just tried using the correct order and it works fine for me.

Comment: Thanks @Umberto Manganiello